# Cambiar icono mark de google maps API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tengo un mapa con marcadores personalizados sacados de una base de datos MySQL.
Con este código inserto dentro de la variable locations las direcciones en coordenadas de mi tabla.

```js
var locations = [
      <?php
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
       ?>
      <?php if ($row['parametro'] != "5"): ?>
        <?php echo "{lat: " . $row['lat'] . ", lng: " . $row['lng'] . "},"; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
      <?php } ?>
      ]
```

Quedaría de esta forma

```js
var locations = [
        {lat: 51.958623, lng: -0.159154},
        {lat: 51.958623, lng: -0.159154},
        {lat: 51.958623, lng: -0.159154},
        etc etc etc
      ]
```

Y funciona correctamente, pero me gustaría saber cómo cambiar los iconos de las marcas como este, en iconos personalizados

[image: Icono google maps]

Este es el código completo

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 8,
              center: {lat: 41.6041581, lng: -3.980962}
            });

            var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';


            var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
              return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                label: labels[i % labels.length]
              });
            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
                {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como está en la documentación de la [API de Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es) la imagen de los iconos se establece en la configuación de los objetos `Marker`.

En tu caso sería algo tal que;

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 8,
              center: {lat: 41.6041581, lng: -3.980962}
            });

            var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

            //Guardar el icono o imagen en una variable
            var img = "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
            
            var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
              return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                label: labels[i % labels.length],
                //Añadir en la configuracion
                icon: img
              });
            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
                {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
          }
```